# Windows 7 cmd Findstr for 2 strings a AND b(not OR)

Tags: findstr

I want to know if there is a way to use findstr to find only those lines in a text file which have both strings a and b.
The following:
findstr "aaa bbb" test.txt
will find all lines with aaa or bbb.
I want all lines with aaa and bbb

Answer (score 2):

#### I want all lines with aaa and bbb

You can use `findstr` twice to achive this, piping the output from the first command to the second.

test.abc:

```
aaa
bbb
aaa bbb
```

...

```
F:\test>findstr "aaa" test.abc | findstr "bbb"
aaa bbb
```

The example search strings are quoted as they could potentially contain spaces.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use two commands successively:

```
findstr "aaa" test.txt | findstr "bbb"
```

This won't work on wild-card file names where only the file names are listed (`/m` option). In this case use the alternative:

```
findstr "aaa.*bbb bbb.*aaa" test.txt
```

This works well for two search strings, but becomes very complex when there are three or more strings to search.